# Logging into Facebook with the phone number

Tags: facebook, login

In Facebook, where you type your username, it says "E-mail or phone". Can you login to Facebook using your phone somehow? Would the password be the same as the e-mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your phone number in the [`Account settings`](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=mobile). Once you did it, you can use your phone number as a user name with the same password you've used with your email or user-name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd be able to log in with the same password that you'd use with your email, if you used your phone number. According to this [Facebook FAQ](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=100530880039294):

> If you signed up for Facebook from your mobile phone, you can use your
>   phone number and the password you created during the sign up process
>   to log in on from a computer or phone.